# Adding additional input text after cloning JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I'm relatively new to Javascript/jQuery and I'm trying to clone a form to record scores. I can add as many input as I want to the pre-cloned form but I can't add, nor remove, any additional text inputs in the subsequent cloned forms.

Let's say before I add a pre-requisite, I placed in 5 input boxes. In that first form, I can remove and add as many input boxes as I want.

Now let's say I add a prequisite, it will clone the first form, but in the cloned form I cannot add nor remove any of the input boxes. That is my issue.

At this point I am stumped on how to fix this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".form-input");
  var add_button = $(".add_item");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="items[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});

//Write code to clone form here, but set everything to default and add
//a button to remove any prerequisites.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctr = 1;
  $(".add_req").click(function() {
    $(".myForm").eq(0)
      .clone()
      .find("input")
      .val("")
      .end()
      .show()
      .insertAfter(".myForm:last");
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".remove-req", function() {
    $(this).closest('.myForm').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="all">
    <button class="add_req">Add Preq-Requisite</button>
    <form class="myForm">
      <section class="selection-menus">

        <select name="major" class="major">
          <option selected="selected">SELECT MAJOR</option>
          <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
          <option value="CIS">Computer Information Systems</option>
        </select>

        <select name="course-no" class="course-no">
          <option value="CS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CS_140">140</option>
          <option value="CS_210">210</option>
          <option value="CS_220">220</option>

          <!--THERE IS NO CIS DATA, THIS IS JUST FOR FUNCTIONALITY-->
          <option value="CIS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CIS_315">315</option>
          <option value="CIS_330">330</option>
          <option value="CIS_497">497</option>
        </select>

        <button class="add_item">Add Item</button>

      </section>

      <div class="form-input">
        <div><input type="text" name="items[]"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="remove-req">Remove Req</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question. It's more like a statement that begs me to ask more questions. Like what does *"Now let's say I add a prequisite, it will clone the first form, but in the cloned form I cannot add nor remove any of the input boxes. That is my issue."* mean?

Comment: @StackSlave In a nutshell: The dynamically added `<span>` element doesn't trigger the click event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the way you select your `wrapper` element.

When the page loads you get the `wrapper` element with `$(".form-input");`. This means you have now selected the elements with the `.form-input` class that are currently on the page. This works fine.

However, from here you clone your form and create a second element with the `.form-input`, that comes from the original form. But the difference here is that the `wrapper` variable never found this second `.form-input` because it didn't exist yet. Same will count for all consequent `.form-input` elements.

A fix for this is to change the event listener for `.remove_field`. Instead of listening to only the first `wrapper`, listen on the `document` for the `click`. All clicks eventually bubble to the document, unless they're intercepted and stopped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".form-input");
  var add_button = $(".add_item");

  var x = 1;
  $(document).on('click', '.add_item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $formInput = $this.parent().next();
    
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $formInput.append('<div><input type="text" name="items[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});

//Write code to clone form here, but set everything to default and add
//a button to remove any prerequisites.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctr = 1;
  $(".add_req").click(function() {
    $(".myForm").eq(0)
      .clone()
      .find("input")
      .val("")
      .end()
      .show()
      .insertAfter(".myForm:last");
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".remove-req", function() {
    $(this).closest('.myForm').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="all">
    <button class="add_req">Add Preq-Requisite</button>
    <form class="myForm">
      <section class="selection-menus">

        <select name="major" class="major">
          <option selected="selected">SELECT MAJOR</option>
          <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
          <option value="CIS">Computer Information Systems</option>
        </select>

        <select name="course-no" class="course-no">
          <option value="CS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CS_140">140</option>
          <option value="CS_210">210</option>
          <option value="CS_220">220</option>

          <!--THERE IS NO CIS DATA, THIS IS JUST FOR FUNCTIONALITY-->
          <option value="CIS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CIS_315">315</option>
          <option value="CIS_330">330</option>
          <option value="CIS_497">497</option>
        </select>

        <button class="add_item">Add Item</button>

      </section>

      <div class="form-input">
        <div><input type="text" name="items[]"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="remove-req">Remove Req</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would recommend that you didn't clone the entire `<form>` element, as I can imagine that all data has to be sent as a whole. But each `<form>` element is its own entity and won't work together with other forms.

Comment: @ikiK, you're correct. They are now fixed.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier So would you recommend I wrap the main meat of the form in a div and clone div so that way it's all still inside the form?

Like <form class = "..."><div class = "container> --code-- </div> </form>

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then the `.container` element would be the element that you'd clone. When you would submit all values of all added fields will be send in a single form.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Cool! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use :

```
  var wrapper = $(".form-input");
  var add_button = $(".add_item");
```

As when you add new form those selectors wont work anymore, and your added add button did not have any events on them.
Instead use:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".add_item", function(e) {
```

If you target document on something that something can be dynamically added and targeted.
and later:

```
$(e.target).parents(".myForm").find(".form-input")
```

target click target and search for appropriate element to append to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;


  var x = 1;
  $(document).on("click", ".add_item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(e.target).parents(".myForm").find(".form-input").append('<div><input type="text" name="items[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(".form-input").on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});

//Write code to clone form here, but set everything to default and add
//a button to remove any prerequisites.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctr = 1;
  $(".add_req").click(function() {
    $(".myForm").eq(0)
      .clone()
      .find("input")
      .val("")
      .end()
      .show()
      .insertAfter(".myForm:last");
  });
  $('.all').on('click', ".remove-req", function() {
    $(this).closest('.myForm').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="all">
    <button class="add_req">Add Preq-Requisite</button>
    <form class="myForm">
      <section class="selection-menus">

        <select name="major" class="major">
          <option selected="selected">SELECT MAJOR</option>
          <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
          <option value="CIS">Computer Information Systems</option>
        </select>

        <select name="course-no" class="course-no">
          <option value="CS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CS_140">140</option>
          <option value="CS_210">210</option>
          <option value="CS_220">220</option>

          <!--THERE IS NO CIS DATA, THIS IS JUST FOR FUNCTIONALITY-->
          <option value="CIS_000">SELECT COURSE</option>
          <option value="CIS_315">315</option>
          <option value="CIS_330">330</option>
          <option value="CIS_497">497</option>
        </select>

        <button class="add_item">Add Item</button>

      </section>

      <div class="form-input">
        <div><input type="text" name="items[]"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="remove-req">Remove Req</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```